# Rationality or otherwise of one angle included by two sides each having distinct integer lengths in an acute-angled scalene triangle

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

**To rephrase this question completely.** If a triangle ABC has three different acute angles, ie no right angle or greater, and has two integer-length sides, the sides opposite the vertices A and B, say, and if the angle opposite the third side is $z\pi$, with $z>1/3$ must $z$ be a rational number or must it be an irrational number, or could it be either?

Thanks for all replies to the original question but please ignore that question, now. (*It was misleading and read: Can a triangle include an irrational angle - by which I mean an angle in radians which is the product of an irrational number and $\pi$? It seems to me that if one angle is $z\pi$, with $z$ an irrational number, then the sum of this angle and either of the other two must be an irrational multiple of $\pi$ as well and therefore that the sum of all three must be be an irrational multiple of $\pi$. But the sum of the three angles must be $\pi$. Is there a flaw in my argument?*)

Comment: Your error is in thinking that the sum of three irrationals must be irrational.  But $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2 -2\sqrt 2=0$ is a counterexample to that.  Or $\log_{30}2+\log_{30}3+\log_{30}5$, say.

Comment: Well an angle of a triangle cannot be negative and the sum of all three numbers must be 1 so that rules out your first counterexample. I shall have to think about the second.

Comment: If $ABC$ is a right angled triangle with $AB = 1$ and $BC = 2$ and $\angle ABC = 90^\circ$, then $\angle CAB$ is an irrational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: @stevepuzzled  my counterexample was for the claim that three irrationals must sum to an irrational.  You can easily make all three terms positive by, say, adding $2$ to the last one.  Anyway, the second example sums to $1$ (obviously) so you can use it directly.

Comment: Would it make any difference if I said the triangle had to be a scalene triangle, with all the angles less than 90° and with integer length sides containing the angle I am concerned about?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be *any* positive real numbers such that $0<\alpha+\beta<1$. Then there is a triangle with angles
$$\alpha\pi,\,\beta\pi,\,(1-\alpha-\beta)\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

Why would that be a problem? Here is a triangle (which happens to be an isosceles one) in which all angles, when measured in radians, are irrational multiples of $\pi$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks José, it's only a problem in that (as I said in my later comment) the triangle needs to be a scalene triangle, without a right angle, in fact with three different acute angles, and with the two sides forming the angle I am mainly concerned about being different integer lengths - an isosceles triangle won't do it. Essentially, I am hoping to establish that such an angle must be a rational multiple of pi and so far I have found no way to prove this.

Comment: Yes, it was a **later** comment. What I posted was an answer to the **original** question.